# infinite scroll pagination javascript implementation issues

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll pagination with javascript in jsfiddle but i am having issues getting it to work properly. I am not seeing the fading in when scrolling and when i reach the end of the content i am supposed to get the message that there is no more data but instead it says it is waiting for more data.

The original example: http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/

My implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/jsuHD/

I added an External Resource to the jsfiddle: scrollpagination.js

I think my problem is with the javascript and not knowing what to pass in as `contentPage`

```
$(function(){
            $('#content').scrollPagination({
                'contentPage': 'http://jsfiddle.net/jsuHD/', // the url you are fetching the results
                'contentData': {}, // these are the variables you can pass to the request, for example: children().size() to know which page you are
                'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
                'heightOffset': 10, // it gonna request when scroll is 10 pixels before the page ends
                'beforeLoad': function(){ // before load function, you can display a preloader div
                    $('#loading').fadeIn();
                },
                'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){ // after loading content, you can use this function to animate your new elements
                     $('#loading').fadeOut();
                     var i = 0;
                     $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
                     if ($('#content').children().size() > 100){ // if more than 100 results already loaded, then stop pagination (only for testing)
                        $('#nomoreresults').fadeIn();
                        $('#content').stopScrollPagination();
                     }
                }
            });

            // code for fade in element by element
            $.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
                var delay = 0;
                return this.each(function(){
                    $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
                    delay += 100;
                });
            };

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you fire up the console **[f12 in google chrome]** you will see that when you reach the end of the page a **403 forbidden** request is made to jsFiddle itself. Yes I think the problem is in what you are  passing to contentPage.

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jsuHD/10/ of your solution. When you load the html from an external source which allows you to get the resource you want, it works as expected.

```
 //load the html from external resource
'contentPage': 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4001846/sample.html'
```

Comment: it is the external resource (scrollpagination) that throw that error. when copied into the start of the javascript, everything worked. http://jsfiddle.net/z9VAh/